# Different page numbering in pdf and pdf-viewer with article class

Tags: pdf, texmaker, viewers

I have a problem with the displayed page numbers in a pdf-viewer.

I make use of Texmaker on Microsoft Windows and the "article" class.

Short example of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%freie Randabstände
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=5cm]{geometry}
%für deutsche Umlaute
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%für westliche Schrift
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Schriftart
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    colorlinks=true, 
    linktoc=all,     
    linkcolor=black,  
}
%Beginn des Dokuments

\begin{document}
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{titlepage}
        bla
    \end{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \section{Das Unternehmen}
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

And my problem while viewing it is:

[image]

I opened a new question, because in every other posts they used the report class or something other than article.

How can I achieve, that a pdf-viewer won't declare my titel- and contentpages with number 1? Instead no lisiting symbole/number would be the best.

Something like a "#" or similar is also pleasing, if the "best case" can't be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%freie Randabstände
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=5cm]{geometry}
%für deutsche Umlaute
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%für westliche Schrift
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Schriftart
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    colorlinks=true, 
    linktoc=all,     
    linkcolor=black,  
}
%Beginn des Dokuments

\begin{document}
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
    \let\oldthepage\thepage
    \def\thepage{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{titlepage}
        bla
    \end{titlepage}
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \let\thepage\oldthepage
    \section{Das Unternehmen}
    \newpage
    test
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

I tested on linux and my pdfviewer doesn't show a number before the first page (it is empty till then)

Feel free to ask me to delete it.

Comment: Thanks for help. It produces an empty output for the pagenumber like I want it. Fits my needs perfect.

Comment: Welcome @T.Ger.  Glad that helped.